# WP7 - RestSharp - Cannot get returned data in XML format

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, restsharp

I use RestSharp in my Windows Phone 7.1 project.

My problem is I cannot get returned response data in XML format, my response always in JSON, while my server supports both JSON and XML.

Example:
URL: http://timtim.vn:8080/fktw/services/timhot/photo/15732

As you see, server can return XML. But in my project, RestSharp response is JSON format. I have set RequestFormat `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;` but it doesn't work!

With JsonDeserializer, I still deserialize response perfectly, but I want to know the reason for this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that RestSharp has per default 6 ContentTypes (you can see them in ContentTypes prorperty of the RestClient object. The first ContentType is "application/json". So for RestClient that content type is the first it will request, as http://timtim.vn:8080/fktw/services/timhot/photo/15732 supports JSON then the response content type is JSON.

If you remove it by coding: `client.RemoveHandler("application/json");` then the response content type will be XML, that is actually the next ContentType preference.

However I don't know how force explicity the client's ContentType preference.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick I drop into the line after the Client declaration:

```
client.ClearHandlers();
client.AddHandler("application/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
client.AddHandler("text/xml", new XmlDeserializer());
```